# Postgresql JDBC Maven. Не подключается к базе данных после сборки

Tags: java, postgresql, maven

начал изучать JDBC и столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Написал простейшую программу в IntellijIDEA, которая пытается подключаться к базе данных Postgresql.
При запуске программы из идешки - все работает, а когда уже собираю проект и пытаюсь запустить - ошибка. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблемы?
Версия java в проекте - 1.8
После запуска выскакивает Exception, говорящий о том, что подключиться не удалось

Код:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Solution {
    public Connection connection(String database) {
        Connection connection = null;
        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/" + database.trim();
        String user = "postgres";
        String pass = "postgres";
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
            System.out.println("Connected to " + database + " database.");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: not connected to database.");
        }
        return connection;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        Solution solution = new Solution();
        solution.connection("gregs_list");
    }
}
```

Maven pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>test</groupId>
<artifactId>test</artifactId>
<version>0.1</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<!-- Зависимости -->
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- PostgreSQL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.9</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>Solution</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

(Вопрос не относящийся к основной части: можно ли откуда-то взять jre выше 8? кроме как с oracle, т.к. требуется учетка и, возможно, оплата. Или можно как-то запустить проект, написанный на 11 и выше с помощью jre 8?)

Comment: Попробовал достать сообщение из Exception: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost/gregs_list

Comment: А где и как вы запускаете? На сервере?

Comment: да, домашний компьютер выступает в роли сервера

Comment: Добавил Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");, вывод поменялся. снова что-то не то
$ java -jar test-0.1.jar
Hello World
org.postgresql.Driver

Comment: Возможно вам надо как-то отдельно на компьютер установить драйвер. Обычно это дополнительная опция при установке postgres. Может быть в этом дело?

Comment: пробовал закинуть библиотеку в c:\program files\java\java8\lib, не дало результатов

Comment: Зачем подключаться через код, если INTELIJ предлагает более быстрое и легкое подключение через вкладку database?

Comment: в рамках обучения)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо скачать библиотеку [JDBC Postgresql](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html) и закинуть в c:\program files\java\jre\lib\ext